# asp.net mvc: how to keep data information to pass it from one element to another screen in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created JS demo that has multiple listings. Each listing has a div with car details like name, price and kms. Along with this, each listing has two buttons "call" & "chat" to help the user to connect to the seller of this listing.

The fiddle demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hfkpu1gp/). Example code:

```
<li>1st listing
<div>
 <p>Model:Audi | Price:1,00,000,000 | Kilometers:1,000</p>
</div>
<button class="call" data-model="Audi" data-price="100000000" data-id="#1">call</button>
<button class="chat" data-model="Audi" data-price="100000000" data-kms="1000" data-id="#1">chat</button>
</li>
```

I have a couple of doubts regarding bindings of information. I have MVC app so all attributes i.e. data-model, data-price etc. & information in each HTML element gets bound through the server.

Both of these buttons "call" & "chat" opens a pop up with different information and on confirmation on the pop up needs to hit different APIs. I have currently done duplicate bindings on both the buttons which isn't efficient way. How should such bindings be handled?

These buttons (chat/call) can be part of li as shown in example OR part of div where the listing is shown independently to the user (i.e. product details page of e-commerce). How should binding of these buttons be handled?

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the values of the `data-` attributes to dialogs?

Comment: Yes. We want to pass specific data- field to the respective dialog

Comment: Why not put in the parent element (and use `var container = $(this).closest('li'); var model = container.data('model');` etc (and if the container element type could vary, give it a class name and use `$(this).closest('.yourClassname');`)